# Help Finalizing this mySQL Date range Insert

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that stores a `start_date` and a `end_date` for a given booking.
This allows me to search the homes and provide available bookings.  Then I decided to use a calendar to show the user what days were booked on the items booking page.  I decided use the AJAX Availability Calendar in the short run since I am short on time.  However, this table for this calendar stores all dates instead of just start and end.  So my thought is to just create a script that will populate the calendar booking date table based on the start_date and end_date.  So basically I need to identify all dates in between including start and end.

I have this script below that does fill the dates into the calendar table. However I also need to INPUT in the item_id and the item_name along with the DATE in each row.  I have tried modifying the SELECT statement to do this but I am just not getting it since it is using sprintf( function.

Here is the script I am using:

```
<?php
$db = array ( 
    'host' => 'myhost', 
    'user' => 'mycalendar', 
    'pass' => 'mypass', 
    'dbname' => 'myDB' 
); 

if(!mysql_connect($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['pass'])) 
{ 
    trigger_error('Connexion error: '.mysql_error()); 
} 
elseif(!mysql_select_db($db['dbname'])) 
{ 
    trigger_error('Error on selecting database '.mysql_error()); 
} 
else 
{ 
    $sql = "SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ANSI,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'"; 
    if(!mysql_query($sql)) 
    { 
        trigger_error('MySQL in ANSI niet mogelijk'); 
    } 
}

// sample data from user input:
$start_date = ('2011-08-21');
$end_date = ('2011-08-21');


// create values for each date:
$startTime = strtotime($start_date);
$endTime = strtotime($end_date);
$values = array();
for($time = $startTime; $time <= $endTime; $time = strtotime('+1 day', $time))
{
   $thisDate = date('Y-m-d', $time);
   $values[] = "('$thisDate')";
}

// build the actual query:
$sql = sprintf(
   "INSERT INTO bookings (the_date), (id_state) VALUES\n%s",
   implode(",\n", $values)
);

// show what query would look like:
echo "<pre>$sql</pre>";

/*
if(!$res = mysql_query($sql)) 
{ 
    trigger_error(mysql_error().'<br />In query: '.$sql); 
} 
else 
{ 
    $id = mysql_insert_id(); 
} 
*/
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed some parts, 1234 is the `id_state`

```
$values[] = "('$thisDate', 1234)";
```

and

```
"INSERT INTO bookings (the_date, id_state) VALUES\n%s",
```

ofcourse you can add other fields/data in similar fashion.

Comment: Oh I feel silly now that I see what you did.  I didn't see that before.  Thanks very much for you help.